# Permutation test appropriate for serially correlated data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, autocorrelation, permutation-test

In my data, I have 575 genes. In every gene, I have a density value associated at every position. Based on criteria specific to my research question, I have  classified the gene positions into either bound region or unbound region (The density profile for one gene is shown below as example).

[image]

My primary goal is to determine **if there is any statistically significant mean difference between the bound and unbound region?**.

I believed a t-test would be good but the density values at gene positions in both bound and unbound region are serially correlated implying that the observations in both samples are not independent (ACF plot shown for the above gene).

[image]

I have implemented a random permutation test where I shuffle the density values across the gene keeping the region boundaries fixed. I would like to know if this approach is valid? Does a permutation test require the assumption of independence of data points?

Also are there any **better approaches to test the statistically significant difference between the bound and unbound regions?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: give example data and example code you wrote, then add the tag, for example R or Matlab or ...